# Running tally of events within a given period with datetime

Tags: python

I have a txt file with a number of dates, each signifying an event:

```
15MAR18 103000      
15MAR18 120518      
17MAR18 121203      
17MAR18 134443      
17MAR18 151733      
19MAR18 165013      
19MAR18 182253      
19MAR18 195533
```

I am trying to get a running tally of how many 'events' occur within a 24 hour time period.

I can read the file and parse into datetime objects ok:

```
for line in range(0, len(event_list):
     eventTime = event_list[line][:14]
     eventTime = datetime.strptime(eventTime, '%d%b%y %H%M%S')

     eventTime_next = event_list[line+1][:14]
     eventTime_next = datetime.strptime(next, '%d%b%y %H%M%S')
```

I don't know how to next go about it.

I tried to compare the line ahead with the previous and but I don't think that's the way to go about it.

I need it so the following happens

```
15MAR18 103000      1
15MAR18 120518      2
17MAR18 121203      1
17MAR18 134443      2
17MAR18 151733      3
19MAR18 165013      1
19MAR18 182253      2
19MAR18 195533      3
```

I.e So the count will go back to 1 when 24 hours has elapsed since the first comparison... and then start again with the new start reference.

I hope this makes sense?

Or is this something for pandas library or something?

Comment: Pandas-based solution below. If you clarify that time is important (it's not in the data you provided), then it can be refactored.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to `pandas`, `pd.Series.cumcount` is one way. This method uses `Date` only to extract the running total.

I'm not sure whether you also need to consider Time.

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

mystr = StringIO("""15MAR18 103000      
15MAR18 120518      
17MAR18 121203      
17MAR18 134443      
17MAR18 151733      
19MAR18 165013      
19MAR18 182253      
19MAR18 195533""")

# replace mystr with 'file.csv' below
df = pd.read_csv(mystr, header=None, names=['Date', 'Time'], delim_whitespace=True)

df['RunningTotal'] = df.groupby('Date').cumcount() + 1

#       Date    Time  RunningTotal
# 0  15MAR18  103000             1
# 1  15MAR18  120518             2
# 2  17MAR18  121203             1
# 3  17MAR18  134443             2
# 4  17MAR18  151733             3
# 5  19MAR18  165013             1
# 6  19MAR18  182253             2
# 7  19MAR18  195533             3
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with what [jpj](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9209546/jpp) suggested.
If you want to go with core, you can try like this:-

```
data = '''15MAR18 103000      
15MAR18 120518      
17MAR18 121203      
17MAR18 134443      
17MAR18 151733      
19MAR18 165013      
19MAR18 182253      
19MAR18 195533    
'''
data_list = data.split('\n')

date_list = []
for data_line in data_list:
    data_date = data_line.split(' ')[0].strip()

    if data_date != '':
        if len(date_list)>0:
            count = 1
            for dict1 in date_list:
                if data_date in dict1['line'].strip():
                    count += 1
        else:
            count = 1
        date_list.append({'line':data_line.strip(), 'count':str(count)})

for data in date_list:
    print(data['line'] +'   ' + data['count'])
```

Output will show like this :

```
15MAR18 103000  1
15MAR18 120518  2
17MAR18 121203  1
17MAR18 134443  2
17MAR18 151733  3
19MAR18 165013  1
19MAR18 182253  2
19MAR18 195533  3
```

[image]

All the best... Happy coding :)